# How to determine the origin of a Python exception

Tags: python, exception

I'm debugging a complex program that has a block like this:

```
try:
  lots()
  of()
  deeply()
  nested()
  code()
except BaseException as e:
  log_error(str(e))
```

The error message that comes out is just `Config file missing` but that's not much help to me.

I'd really like to see exactly were that message comes from.
(Note that the error string is from an external program, so it's not searchable.)

If I use `traceback` I only get to see the stack trace *after* it's been wound back to the handler, which is not useful. I'd like to see the traceback at the *source* of the exception.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: "If I use traceback I only get to see the stack trace after it's been wound back to the handler" - you're probably using `traceback` wrong. That module does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Remove the try/except - then the error will cause an immediate trace of the call hierarchy to console. But yes I agree with @user2357112 that you must be using traceback wrongly.

Comment: So in a test file, I see that it does do exactly what you're suggesting. Which is great. I just have to figure out why it's not working in my real program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging purposes you can use traceback module to print stack trace

```
import traceback

try:
    lots()
    of()
    deeply()
    nested()
    code()
except BaseException as e:
    print traceback.format_exc()
    log_error(str(e))
```

Comment: Thanks. This does indeed work in my test program, but not in the real program I'm debugging.